# Extract data from AWS Glue Data Catalog to a text file externally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am writing a python script which should read metadata (only the schema) present in AWS Glue Data Catalog and write it to text files.
How to go about this?

Comment: Please add your python script and add more details to the question, what exactly in glue catalog you are trin to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the boto3 python api for querying the table metadata from glue catalog.

Sample code:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('glue')
response = client.get_table(
    DatabaseName='<your_database_name>',
    Name='<your_table_name>'
)
print response
```

You can parse to response (json) to extract the required metadata and dump it to file.

Reference documentation: [Boto3 - Glue Catalog - Get Table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_table)

Comment: getting the error: botocore.errorfactory.EntityNotFoundException: An error occurred (EntityNotFoundException) when calling the GetTable operation: Database sampledb not found.   Can you tell me how to run this succesfully

Comment: The error message clearly states that there is no database named sampledb in your glue catalog. Could you verify?

Comment: Ya there was no database called sampledb. Thanks alot :)